# java.lang.Exception: who's calling? while making call over PJSUA

Tags: java, android, pjsip, pjsua2

I am implementing PJSUA2 in my android application for voip call. Based on app requirement, sometimes I try to make fast calls, like starting the call and disconnecting it within 1 second and trying again connecting the call. During this, my App is crashing after some times of continuous calling and disconnecting (Around 5- 10 secs). I am getting an exception saying: **java.lang.Exception: who's calling?**

I am only using UDP for VoIP calls and commented TCP and TSL channels as it used to give **Transport not supported exception** at the same scenario (Continuous calls)
    I will post my setup of transport below. Please have a look:

```
            /* Create transports. */
        try {

            ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP,
                       sipTpConfig);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            Log.d("excmicbutton","1st"+e.getMessage());
        }

//      try {
//          ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP,
//                     sipTpConfig);
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          System.out.println(e);
//          Log.d("excmicbutton","2nd"+e.getMessage());
//      }
//
//      try {
//          sipTpConfig.setPort(SIP_PORT +1);
//          ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS,
//                     sipTpConfig);
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          System.out.println(e);
//          Log.d("excmicbutton","3rd"+e.getMessage());
//      }

            /* Set SIP port back to default for JSON saved config */
            sipTpConfig.setPort(SIP_PORT);

        /* Create accounts. */
        for (int i = 0; i < accCfgs.size(); i++) {
            MyAccountConfig my_cfg = accCfgs.get(i);

            /* Customize account config */
            my_cfg.accCfg.getNatConfig().setIceEnabled(true);
            my_cfg.accCfg.getVideoConfig().setAutoTransmitOutgoing(true);
            my_cfg.accCfg.getVideoConfig().setAutoShowIncoming(true);

            MyAccount acc = addAcc(my_cfg.accCfg);
            if (acc == null)
            continue;
```